# Varnish client.ip says 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, nginx, varnish, x-forwarded-for

So I have a setup like Nginx -> varnish -> apache2
If I get a request with a static file it is sent through nginx to varnish and back to nginx again since its a lot faster than letting apache2 server it. My problem is that when I do a

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    set beresp.http.X-Tabulex-Client = client.ip;
```

to see what the clients ip address is I am being told its 127.0.0.1 (X-Tabulex-Client   127.0.0.1) In the vcl_recv I have:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if ((!req.url ~"^/typo3temp/*" && !req.url ~"^/typo3/*") &&req.url ~"\.(jpg|css|gif|png|js)(\?.*|)$"){
        set req.backend = aurum;
        set client.identity = req.http.X - Forwarded - For;
    } elseif(client.ip == "192.168.3.189") {
        /* Traffic from the other Varnish server, serve using real backends */
        set req.backend = balance;
        /* Set client.identity to the X-Forwarded-For (the real IP) */
        set client.identity = req.http.X - Forwarded - For;
    } else{
        /* Traffic coming from internet, use the other Varnish as backend */
        set req.backend = iridium;
    }
}
```

The nginx config contains

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_intercept_errors on;
```

when sending to varnish the first time and nothing when receiving from varnish again.

Im not sure where the problem is. I would expect the client.ip to contain the external ip address so I could use it for acl. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `client.ip` is `127.0.0.1` because `nginx` is the client.  It wouldn't make sense for Varnish to mask this value -- even in situations like yours where Varnish is sitting behind a front-end proxy, you often want to base decisions on the ip address of the thing actually making the connecting to Varnish.

What you really want to do is have `nginx` put the remote client ip address into a dedicated header  (which you're already doing with `X-Real-IP`) and use that for making connection decisions.  We do exactly this in our environment where we have Apache provided SSL connectivity in front of `varnish`, and then we use this header to make access decisions.

It's not as nice as using `client.ip` (you can't match it using `acl`s), but it works.  We do something like this:

```
if (! (
        req.http.X-Real-IP ~ "^10\." ||
        req.http.X-Real-IP ~ "^100\.100\." ||
        req.http.X-Real-IP ~ "^200\.200\."
)) {
        error 403 "Forbidden";
}
```

Varnish doesn't provide a native mechanism for overriding `client.ip` with a custom header, but it is *possible* to solve the problem anyway because you can insert arbitrary C code into your configuration.

[Here](http://zcentric.com/2012/03/16/varnish-acl-with-x-forwarded-for-header/) is an example that exactly parallels your situation that includes an example of replacing `client.ip` with another value so that it can be used in Varnish ACLs.

Comment: Makes sence. I couldnt find any documentation on how the client works. Am I able to overwrite client.ip somehow? As you said yourself its the normal way of doing ACL :)

Comment: So I tried your approach but I cant seem to get it working.       `if (req.http.Cache-Control ~ "no-cache" && req.http.X-Real-IP ~ "^111\.111\.111\.111") {
                ban(req.url);
                return (pass);
        }` also tried ip address just using "111.111.111.111"

Comment: Are these rules matching?  What does your `varnishlog` output show for a single request?

Comment: Sorry it is working. It does recognize my IP address but it dosent ban the file. I think this is due to the communication between the two varnish caches. I get the new file when doing a no-cache hit but as soon as I make a normal request I get the old file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Varnish as your front-end webserver (our backend is NGINX) behind a Rackspace Cloud Load Balancer, then you need to use a pattern like the following:

```
if (!(
    req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ "1\.2\.3\.4" || 
    req.http.X-Forwarded-For ~ "2\.3\.4\.5" 
    )) {
    # IP-based Rules
}
```

Rackspace Cloud Load Balancer won't pass anything but `127.0.0.1` to Varnish as `client.ip`. Also, I tried using a more restrictive pattern, like `^2\.3\.4\.5$` but it wouldn't match. I think the load balancer was adding extra characters to the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Answer (score 1):

If req.http.X-Real-IP is available in your request then you can use the function ip() of the std module to convert a string (like req.http.X-Real-IP) to a type IP and then use the ~ operator to compare it to an ACL list. This is more efficient than comparing multipe times with some IP strings.

`acl aclRestricted {
    "1.1.1.1";
    "2.2.2.2";
}
if (std.ip(req.http.X-Real-IP, "0.0.0.0") ~ aclRestricted ) {
    ...
}`

Reference Varnish V4.1: https://varnish-cache.org/docs/4.1/reference/vmod_std.generated.html#func-ip